# Update tableView height on basis of number of sections

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I want to adjust my *tableview height* according to the number of sections using auto layout.

Number of sections may `vary.Data` for section one and two is not fixed.
Each section is having different data.

Beneath the TableView their are other components (`UILabel`, `UIButton`) and they are fixed but adjust their position if `tableView` shrinks or expands (TableView max height = height of view).

I don't want to give a static height.

`UITableView` constraint's height will be changed in `viewDidLoad`?

How to implement it?

Comment: Please explain, your question looks very generic!

Comment: As i sad earlier i want to update my tableview height using auoLayout on the basis of how many sections did the table view has.As the no. of sections may vary.

Comment: @TabishSohail a UITableview scrolls when its content is too tall, if you increase the size of it instead it will not scroll. Your question makes no sense

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin .It actually makes sense Sir.
There are other components also beneath the table view and they are fixed.But adjust accordingly if the tableView shrinks.ANd obviously Tableview will scroll as there will be a MAX Height defined for this.

Comment: @TabishSohail you haven't explained any of this. Most likely why there was a downvote. Your question is very confusing, please edit it and reword

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I have edited my query and this time much clear i think.I don't know who has down-voted.

Comment: Not need to change the table height, change cell height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is achievable with just autoLayout. I believe you will need to do some calculations and either modify constraints that have been setup in IB or add them yourself in code.

A `tableView` is essentially a `scrollView`, and when using these in `autoLayout` you have to provide 2 pieces of information

1. The size of the `tableView` / `scrollView`
2. The size of the `contentView`

With a `tableView`, 2 is handled for you, but you have to give a size to each row, which `autoLayout` can calculate for you using the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` callback and the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` method.

These 2 aspects are treated differently and I'm not aware of a means to join them. As far as I know, it was designed so that you tell the `scrollView` what size / shape to be and give it its content, it will scroll if it has too and it won't if it doesn't, it has no knowledge of the content size in order to resize itself.

Comment: @TabishSohail glad it worked out. Don't forget to mark it as top answer / upvote it so others facing the same issue will no what solved it for you

Comment: Sir thanks for your support.
I have achieved this functionality.Like you said.I've just updated the height constraint in view did load on the basis of the data array's count that each section is going to have.
And there is a maximum height for tableView.
if there are more than one sections _tbleViewHeightConstraint.constant = MAX_TbleViewHeight.
else _tbleViewHeightConstraint.constant=yourArray.count*rowheight

Comment: SOry i can't upvote now as i don't have that much ranking.But surely i will as soon as my ranking will increase

Comment: @TabishSohail as yes I didn't realise that. Marking as top answer will let others know this solved your issue

Answer (score -1):

Try Heightforrowatindexpath delegate to make the size. Then use autolayout based on that hight that which you mention for that section.Better you can alter this through code is most usefull for this situation.

Comment: The user has asked how to increase the tableView height not the row. Further more you have not provided any code or samples